# Chamando function

Tags: javascript

Estou começando em javascript e estou com uma duvida.
Qual a melhor forma de passar instruções para uma function Javascript, vou dar um exemplo atual da forma que estou fazendo, funciona, mas é uma boa pratica ?

```
sistema('/comando2'); //estou chamando assim



        sistema(cmd)
        {  if((req.state == 4) && (req.status == 200))//verifica a request do XMLHttpRequest
            {   
                if(cmd.search("/comando1")>=0) {faz algo//}
                if(cmd.search("/comando2")>=0) {faz algo//}

                }

        }
```

Gostaria de saber também uma boa pratica para criar uma function de requests com XMLHttpRequest, na qual eu mude o parâmetro da URL e os valores de acordo com a necessidade, e trate adequadamente os erros.

Obrigado

Comment: Podes explicar qual a funcionalidade que `sistema` faz no teu código?

Comment: Um gerenciador de arquivos, ele muda de acordo com o valor do "cmd"

Comment: Se conseguires explicar ainda melhor e dar exemplos vou poder responder mais acertado. Senão como estás a fazer parece-me bem, mas não imagino ainda os casos de uso dessa função.

Comment: Eu quero por exemplo clicar em um botão renomear, quando clicar chamar a function com o parâmetro "/renomear/arquivo", ai dentro dela fazer um search e verificar se existe o comando renomear, e então fazer um split para retirar somente o nome do arquivo e enviar para uma requisição com a api.

Comment: Ok, e esse `sistema` faz uma chamada ajax antes ou depois dos `if(cmd.search)`?

Comment: O cmd Search é usado para preencher a url da api e o valor que vai ser enviado com o XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usares o `.search` tens de passar uma *RegExp*. No teu exemplo estás a passar uma *String*.

Como o teu input é uma String, então podes usar o `.includes()` ou o `indexOf`.

Assim podia ficar:

```js
function sistema(cmd) {
  if (cmd.includes("/comando1")) {
    console.log(1);
  }
  if (cmd.includes("/comando2")) {
    console.log(2);
  }
}

sistema('/comando2');
sistema('/comando2');
sistema('/comando1');
```

Não percebo bem como queres usar o `req.state` nesta função pois pertence ao ajax e esse código não está na pergunta pois não está relacionado com o problema provavelmente. Por isso retirei isso da resposta e foquei só na questão de detectar o comando certo.